# I want to set the "privacy policy" at the end of my webpage in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

"Privacy policy" link is shown in the middle of my webpage. I need to set it on the bottom of my page. The below given is my CSS and HTML source codes. I can't able to set it on bottom.

```css
#footer {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
#footer p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>  Copyright&copy; 2016&nbsp;school.pythonanywhere.com.&nbsp;All Rights Reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'privacy' %}">Privacy policy</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change anchor tag  (`a`) default display property with `display:block`.

```css
#footer {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 200px;
}


#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
}


#footer p a{display:block}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>  Copyright&copy; 2016&nbsp;school.pythonanywhere.com.&nbsp;All Rights Reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'privacy' %}">Privacy policy</a></p>
</div>
```

But it will be good if you add `width` in your `a` tag, if you not add `width` then `a` tag will work with blank space on hover.

```
#footer p a{
  display:block;
  max-width:80px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution using `position:absolute;`:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#footer {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
#footer p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>  Copyright&copy; 2016&nbsp;school.pythonanywhere.com.&nbsp;All Rights Reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'privacy' %}">Privacy policy</a></p>
</div>
```

**Hint:** You can use `position:fixed;` too if you want to see the footer all the time at the end of the page (on scrolling too).

**You want the link Privacy Policy" in a new line too?**

You have to set the `<a>` on footer a block element like the following:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#footer {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
#footer p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#footer a {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>  Copyright&copy; 2016&nbsp;school.pythonanywhere.com.&nbsp;All Rights Reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'privacy' %}">Privacy policy</a></p>
</div>
```